# Facing issue while recording mobile traffic through jmeter HTTPS script recorder

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to record mobile traffic through jmeter but not getting success. Can anyone please help.
Steps followed as below:

1. In JMeter added recording template and Setting port to 9090 in
   recorder
2. In mobile below configuration done

> Change wifi with the below setting:  Proxy mode set to manual Given
> hostname = localhost (laptop) ip address  Port = 8888 Installed JMeter
> security certificate and verified it under trusted credential in
> mobile

3. Starting recording in JMeter
4. Launching any site i.e. google on mobile
5. Getting error “You are offline”

Answer (score 0):

The ports **must match**, given you `Setting port to 9090 in recorder` you need to use the port `9090` in your mobile device network proxy configuration.

Also if you're running Android 6.0 or higher you will need to take some extra steps in order to be able to intercept secure traffic like:

1. In [`application` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) of your app manifest add the next line:

   ```
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ```
2. Create `network_security_config.xml` file under your [app resources folder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) and put the following code there:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
       <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
               <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
               <certificates src="user" />
           </trust-anchors>
       </debug-overrides>
   </network-security-config>
   ```
3. [Build your application in debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode)

   ```
   gradlew assembleDebug
   ```
4. Install the .apk onto your device
5. That's it, you should be able to record now

More information:

- [Android network security config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#network-security-config)
- [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices)